# How can I display my what i input in my array element

Tags: java, arrays

This is what I tried but I cant display it, here is my code and I can compile and run it but when I select the display the error shows.

Here are my errors

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 0
    at example.display(example.java:65)
    at example.menu(example.java:153)
    at example.create(example.java:22)
    at example.home(example.java:94)
    at example.main(example.java:9)
```

and still confusing what are my problems.

When I try to run it there are some errors like

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class example
{
   int size;
   int array [] = new int [size];
 public static void main()
 {
    example Obj1 = new example ();
    Obj1.home ();

 }
 
public void create()
{
     Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter size of array: ");
    size = sc.nextInt();
    int [] array = new int [size];
    if (size >= 5 && size <= 20)
    {
        System.out.println("You created a "+size+" elements of array");
       menu();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Error!! try again");
        menu();
    }
}

public void insert()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        // create an array of size n
          int ins;
          if (size >=5 && size<=20)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
              {
                  System.out.print("Enter the elements in an array: ");
                   ins = input.nextInt();
               }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Sorry please create an array more than 5 but less than 20!");
            }
}

public  void display()
{
    int i =size;
    if (size == 0)
    {
        System.out.print("No element to display");
        return;
    }
    
    System.out.print ("Array elements are: ");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(array[size]);
    }
}

public void home()
      {
           int a = 0;   
        String[] choices = {"[1] create array","[2] Insert element", "[3] Display","[0] Stop"};  
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);  
        System.out.printf(" \n\n  Array Operations");
        System.out.println("\n\tMenu \n"); 
        System.out.printf("%s\n", choices[0]);
        System.out.printf("%s\n", choices[1]);
        System.out.printf("%s\n", choices[2]);
        System.out.printf("%s\n", choices[3]);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        a = sc.nextInt();
           do {
               switch(a)
           {
             case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println('\f');
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    create();
                    menu();
                    
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    System.out.println("Error!! Please Create first ");
                    insert ();
                    main();
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    System.out.println("Error!! Please Create first ");
                    display ();
                    main();
                    break;
                }
                
            }
        }while ( a ==1);
        }
        
 public void menu()
  {
        int a = 0;   
        String[] choices = {"[1] create array","[2] Insert element", "[3] Search", "[4] Display", "[5] Delete", "[0] Stop"};  
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);  
        System.out.printf(" \n\n  Array Operations");
        System.out.println("\n\tMenu \n"); 
        System.out.printf("%s\n", choices[0]);
        System.out.printf("%s\n", choices[1]);
        System.out.printf("%s\n", choices[2]);
        System.out.printf("%s\n", choices[3]);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        a = sc.nextInt();
               switch(a)
           {
             case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println('\f');
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    create();
                    menu();
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    insert ();
                    menu();
                    
                }
                case 3:
                {   
                    display ();
                    menu();
                    break;
                }

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int size;   int array [] = new int [size];` at time `new int [size];` is called `size` holds its default value (since it was not explicitly initialized yet) which for `int` is 0 making `int array [] = new int [size];` equivalent of `int array [] = new int [0];`. Also you seem to have two `array` variables, one as field and one local variable in `create` method.

Comment: For now my guess is that your problem is simply typo, and inside `create()` method you shouldn't *declare and assign* value to *new local variable* via `int[] array = ...` but only *assign* value to *already existing field* `array` via `array = ...` (just like you did for `size` variable line above: `size = ...` instead of `int size = ...`).